Explicit upper and lower bounds for a support function, with a different exponent
Let $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \cdots \geq a_n \geq 0$ be a sequence of nonincreasing nonnegative real numbers. Define the set, for $t > 1$,
$$
B_t = \Big\{b \in \mathbb{R}^n : b_i \geq 0, \sum_i b_i^2 \leq 1, \sum_i b_i^{3/2} \leq t\Big\}.
$$
I am interested in upper and lower bounds that differ only in constants (which are independent of $t, a$) for the following
$$
f_t(a) = \max_{b \in B_t} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_j. 
$$
It can be seen as at the support function of $B_t$ for such nonincreasing nonnegative $a$.
In this post, the corresponding quantity is approximately computed when the exponent is not $3/2$ but is instead $1/2$. However, the approach taken there (Lagrange duality) does not seem to help much here (or at least, simplifying the dual seems to be quite challenging).
